# I want to show$X : ((0,1],\mathcal B,\lambda)\to \mathbb R$ is random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $F:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$ be a distribution function of a probability measure $P$ $(i.e.,F(x)=P((-\infty,x])) $. Then show that There is a random variable $X : ((0,1],\mathcal B,\lambda)\to \mathbb R$,(where $\mathcal B$ is the borel $\sigma $-algebra and $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure) ,such  that $P_{X}=P$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard result that you should be able to find in any book on measure-theoretic probability. Look in chapter 1, section 2 [here](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html). It is Theorem 1.2.2.

Comment: I can't find the result in your link. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @StefanHansen I gave the wrong section. It is correct now.