# Explicitly representing a random variable such as $ X(\omega):=\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln \frac{1}{1-\omega}$, which is exponential

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, quantile

Previously: ([Dumb question: Computing expectation without change of variable formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690542/)) I was wondering how to compute $E[X]$ by $\int_{\Omega} X d\mathbb P$ rather than $\int_{\mathbb R} x d \mathcal L_X(x)$, i.e. without the change of variable formula.

Today, I found out ([Distribution function of a random variable in Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755250)) an explicit way to write $X(\omega)$ for an exponentially distributed $X$.

---

Apparently, a random variable $X$ in $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P) =((0,1), \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ with $\mu$ as the Lebesgue measure given by

$$X(\omega):=\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln \frac{1}{1-\omega}$$

has distribution $F_X(x) =  (1-e^{-\lambda x})1_{x \ge 0}$, which we know to be the cdf of an exponentially distributed random variable for $\lambda > 0$. Thus, we can compute

$$E[X] = \int_{\Omega} X d\mathbb P = \int_0^1 \ln \frac{1}{\lambda} \frac{1}{1-\omega} d\mathbb P(\omega) = \int_0^1 \ln \frac{1}{\lambda} \frac{1}{1-\omega} d\mu(\omega) = \int_0^1 \ln \frac{1}{\lambda} \frac{1}{1-\omega} d\omega$$

By change of variable, we can verify that this is the same as $$E[X] = \int_{\mathbb R} x \frac{d}{dx} F_X(x) dx$$

Q1. What's the term for something like $$X(\omega):=\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln \frac{1}{1-\omega}$$ ?

This seems to be an explicit representation of the exponentially distributed random variable $X$. I don't see anything like this on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). By this standard proposition, [I want to show$X : ((0,1],\mathcal B,\lambda)\to \mathbb R$ is random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567937), every distribution function in a probability space implies the existence of a random variable in $((0,1), \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ with $\mu$ as Lebesgue measure, whose CDF is the distribution function's.

Q2. Also, how does one come up with explicit representations for any distribution function?

---

(*) By the way, this relates to my deleted questions:

[Maths Stackexchange: How do you compute expectation w/o change of variable formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537567) or [Maths Overflow: How do you compute expectation w/o change of variable formula?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295749/dumb-question-computing-expectation-without-change-of-variable-formula)

[Maths Stackexchange: Explicitly representing a random variable in terms of indicator functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694657) or [Maths Overflow: Explicitly representing a random variable in terms of indicator functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295738/explicitly-representing-a-random-variable-in-terms-of-indicator-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [Skorokhod representation](https://dbfin.com/probability/williams/chapter-3-random-variables/), according to David Williams' Probability with Martingales.(*) For a given cdf $F$, the random variable can be explicitly represented by computing [$$X(\omega) = \sup\{y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) < \omega\}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888054)

Like for exponential:

$$F(y) < \omega$$

$$\iff 1-e^{-\lambda y} < \omega$$

$$\iff y < \frac{1}{\lambda} \ln(\frac{1}{1-\omega})$$

Thus, $$X(\omega) = \sup(y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) < \omega) = \sup(-\infty,\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln(\frac{1}{1-\omega})) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \ln(\frac{1}{1-\omega})$$

---

(*) This can also be called [canonical representation](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/teaching/2007-08/235B/lecture-notes.pdf) (MAT 235A / 235B: Probability Instructor: Prof. Roman Vershynin Prof typeset by Edward D. Kim) or [Skorokhod representation of random variables using quantile transforms](https://books.google.com/books?id=GDP9CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=%22Skorokhod%20representation%22%20%22quantile%20transforms%22&source=bl&ots=dgV1TNxb0t&sig=V9eLseKuJvrg080GzZLGaiU9bAg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHxuz6uN3aAhWJXLwKHRP2BmUQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Skorokhod%20representation%22%20%22quantile%20transforms%22&f=false) (Optimal Transport Methods in Economics By Alfred Galichon).

Skorokhod representations relate to [quantile functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function), similarly defined:

$$Q(p) = \inf\{x \in \mathbb R | F(x) \ge p\}$$

In the wiki page for random variables under distribution functions, it says:

> The probability distribution "forgets" about the particular probability space used to define X and only records the probabilities of various values of X. [...] In practice, one often disposes of the space $\Omega$ altogether and just puts a measure on $\mathbb {R}$ that assigns measure 1 to the whole real line, i.e., one works with probability distributions instead of random variables.